# How to I pass the data back to the main function for yielding?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner in python programming with the scrapy library. I want to yield the birth_date in the same output with the main output that have title, author, and etc. However, without a success, I couldn't get the result to be shown.

```
import scrapy


class QuotespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotespider"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.css(".quote")
        all_url_tags = quotes.css(".tags a.tag::attr(href)").getall()

        for quote in quotes:
            url_tags = []
            tags = (quote.css(".tags meta.keywords::attr(content)").get()).split(',')
            url_tags = [j for i in tags for j in all_url_tags if i in j] #append only the neccesary url_tags

            url_author = quote.css("span a::attr(href)").get()
            author_page = "https://quotes.toscrape.com/" + url_author

            items = {
                'title' : quote.css("span.text::text").get(),
                'author' : quote.css("span small.author::text").get(),
                'url_author' : quote.css("span a::attr(href)").get(),
                'tags' : tags,
                'url_tags' : url_tags
                }

            #Goes to the page to scrape the author's date of birth
            yield scrapy.Request(url=author_page, callback=self.parse_author_page, meta={'items':items})
            
            yield items

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()

        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_url = "https://quotes.toscrape.com/" + next_page
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_author_page(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        
        birth_date = response.css(".author-details p span.author-born-date::text").get()
        items['birth_date'] = birth_date

        return items
```

These are some of the outputs:

```
{"title": "“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”", "author": "Albert Einstein", "url_author": "/author/Albert-Einstein", "tags": ["change", "deep-thoughts", "thinking", "world"], "url_tags": ["/tag/change/page/1/", "/tag/deep-thoughts/page/1/", "/tag/thinking/page/1/", "/tag/world/page/1/"]},

{"title": "“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”", "author": "J.K. Rowling", "url_author": "/author/J-K-Rowling", "tags": ["abilities", "choices"], "url_tags": ["/tag/abilities/page/1/", "/tag/choices/page/1/"]},

{"title": "“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”", "author": "Albert Einstein", "url_author": "/author/Albert-Einstein", "tags": ["inspirational", "life", "live", "miracle", "miracles"], "url_tags": ["/tag/inspirational/page/1/", "/tag/inspirational/page/1/", "/tag/inspirational/page/1/", "/tag/life/page/1/", "/tag/life/page/1/", "/tag/live/page/1/", "/tag/miracle/page/1/", "/tag/miracles/page/1/", "/tag/miracles/page/1/"]},
```

I want to yield the dict in the main function of parse however, I couldn't get the birth_date to be added to the items in the output.

Thank you in advance for your kindness.

Comment: I'm not expert in Scrapy but it seems that the *parse()* override is not meant to be a generator

Comment: Just yield the dict in `parse_author_page` instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the `yield items` from the *parse* method. If you analyze the logs of your scraped items you are going to see duplicated items. You are yielding items without **birth_date** in the *parse* method and then returning the same item with **birth_date** in the *parse_author_page*. Removing the `yield items` from the *parse* method will make your spider behave the way you want.